# How to clear or update only anonymous cache from module?

Tags: nodes, caching

I have nodes updating from my module in Drupal 7 and also complicated view with result cached in the module by cache_set() and cache_get() functions.

Anonymous users get old info with broken links and other problems after nodes updating in module. Disabling "Cache pages for anonymous users" solves the problem, but how can I update anonymous page cache by the function after update?

I can't just clear all cache because of complicated views cache, it will disable all site for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cache_clear_all()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) is what you need.

If you need to clear cache of only one node page:

```
cache_clear_all('http://yoursite.com/node/' . $node->nid, 'cache_page')
```

(first parameter - cache id, it case of cache_page it is page url).

If you want to clear all pages cache:

```
cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_page', TRUE);
```